# Parse.JS: How can I add a new index to a column type of array?

Tags: javascript, parse.js

Inside my Companies class, I have a column type of array which is called Ratings, it contains pointers to the Ratings class which contains the ratings for the company. It is a one to many relation, one company has several ratings.

When I try to update the data by adding a new Rating to a company, I cannot retain the old data. Instead it overwrites it.

Here is my code for saving a new rating:

```
function addRating(id, rating) {
    var Companies = Parse.Object.extend("Companies");
    var Ratings = Parse.Object.extend("Ratings");

    var company = new Companies({
        objectId: id,
        ratings: [new Ratings({stars: rating})]
    });
    company.save();
}
```

Obviously it overwrites the current ratings field with a pointer to the newly added rating, is it possible to have it add on to the end of the array? Do I have to retrieve the previous value first using a query, and then add the new rating on the old rating array? I'm quite new to this, so I am very lost.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: looks like you are not overwriting `ratings` but creating a new `companies` . Get a reference to your original `companies` and push the new `rating` to its `ratings` array.

Comment: In the data browser it is overwriting the `ratings` field, it's not creating a new `companies` row? `objectId` is targeting the row I am attempting to update.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Parse.js you can add a tag for it if aavailable

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my question, this code is now working for me:

```
function addRating(id, rating) {
    var Companies = Parse.Object.extend("CompaniesArray");
    var Ratings = Parse.Object.extend("RatingsArray");

    var company = new Companies({
         objectId: id
    });

    var rated = new Ratings({stars: rating});
    rated.save({
      success: function() {
        alert('success');
        company.addUnique("ratings", rated);    
        company.save({
            success: function() {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }          
  });
}
```

I needed to save the rating first, then attach it to the company by using the .addUnique method